# How to extract single quoted number from the list in python

Tags: python, dictionary, pyspark

I want to extract the key for my dictionary but the problem is that the key is enclosed in single quotes.

```
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
import collections,shutil,os

conf = SparkConf().setMaster("local").setAppName("Word_count")
sc=SparkContext(conf=conf)

rdd=sc.textFile("/home/karan/dummy files/patient.csv")
rdd2=sc.textFile("/home/karan/dummy files/doctors.csv")
def nameOfDoc():
    names={}
    with open("/home/karan/dummy files/doctors.csv") as l:
        for x in l:
            nameExt=x.split('\t')
            names[int(nameExt[0])]=nameExt[1]
    return names
docName=sc.broadcast(nameOfDoc())

docId=rdd.map(lambda x:x.split(",")).\
        map(lambda x:(x[3],1)).\
        reduceByKey(lambda x,y:x+y).\
        map(lambda x:(x[1],x[0])).\
        sortByKey(ascending=False).\
        map(lambda x:(x[1],x[0]))
rs=docId.collect()
if os.path.exists("/home/karan/output2"):
    shutil.rmtree("/home/karan/output2")
for x in rs:
    print(docName.value[x[0]],end=" -> ")
    print(x[1])
sc.parallelize(rs).saveAsTextFile("output2")
```

My code is giving me this error

> File "/home/karan/hospitalsDemo.py", line 28, in 
>       print(docName.value[x[0]],end=" -> ") KeyError: '2'

Comment: have you tried `int(x[0])` to transform the string `'2'` into the integer `2`?

Comment: yeah it worked thanks bro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for x in rs:
    print(docName.value[x[0]],end=" -> ")
    print(x[1])
```

I think Green Cloak Guy is correct about transforming the string to an integer.
Since you are using x for x[0] and x[1], and also to avoid a case where the key might not convert to an interger, I think you should"

```
for x in rs:
    try:
        xkey = int(x)
    except:
        xkey = x

    print(docName.value[xkey[0]],end=" -> ")
    print(xkey[1])
```